# What is the Mississippi Law and Federal Law against incest?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, family-law, mississippi

What is incest legally and what punishment applies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mississippi [general prohibition](https://codes.findlaw.com/ms/title-97-crimes/ms-code-sect-97-29-5.html) against incest is that

> Persons being within the degrees within which marriages are prohibited
>   by law to be incestuous and void, or persons who are prohibited from
>   marrying by reason of blood and between whom marriage is declared to
>   be unlawful and void, who shall cohabit, or live together as husband
>   and wife, or be guilty of a single act of adultery or fornication,
>   upon conviction, shall be punished by imprisonment in the penitentiary
>   for a term not exceeding ten (10) years.

The degree of relationship declared to prohibit marriage [is defined as](https://codes.findlaw.com/ms/title-93-domestic-relations/ms-code-sect-93-1-1.html)

> (1) The son shall not marry his grandmother, his mother, or his
>   stepmother;  the brother his sister;  the father his daughter, or his
>   legally adopted daughter, or his grand-daughter;  the son shall not
>   marry the daughter of his father begotten of his stepmother, or his
>   aunt, being his father's or mother's sister, nor shall the children of
>   brother or sister, or brothers and sisters intermarry being first
>   cousins by blood.  The father shall not marry his son's widow;  a man
>   shall not marry his wife's daughter, or his wife's daughter's
>   daughter, or his wife's son's daughter, or the daughter of his brother
>   or sister;  and the like prohibition shall extend to females in the
>   same degrees.  All marriages prohibited by this subsection are
>   incestuous and void.

In the US, incest laws are at the state level, not the federal level.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer

Comment: Strange that a father must not marry his son's widow, but apparently may marry the son's ex-wife. Which would be the same person.